# How create a views showing sponsored user profile field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I created a profile field called Sponsor name, who sponsor or introduce him into the website. The sponsor must be a user in the website. A user can sponsor any number of users to the website. When a user wants to register, he must give the sponsor name. I have done it successfully.

Now I want to create a view showing a list of sponsored users corresponding to each user.

for example:
User James sponsor's

- Williams
- Perter
- John

User Williams sponsor's

- Adam
- Jimmy

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to have one page with every user and every person they sponsor? or do you want to have one page per user, with the list of people they sponsor?

Comment: Yes, i want one page per user, with the list of people they sponsor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single page per user, then what you would want to do is to add an argument to your view. Where the argument would be the field you created for the sponsors name, and then in the settings for that argument, you would get the user id or username from the URL.

Comment: I added Sponsor name argument and i set  "Provide default argument" >> "User ID from URL" , but i couldn't produce any result. Please explain. If you mean some other way ?

Comment: Yeah that's the plan. Are you sure you have the user ID in the URL? Also, if you have the user ID in the URL, but the sponsor field is the name of the user, then you either need to write a bit of code to make the user ID into the user name, or pass the username as a parameter instead of the user ID.